# Implementation of Google snappy decompression

Tags: programming, import

[Snappy](http://google.github.io/snappy/) is a compression/decompression library released by Google.  It has been implemented in a variety of languages (see the link), but not Mathematica as far as I can find.  **Does anyone know of an implementation in Mathematica?**  Or at least just the decompression bit.

Comment: Heh, implementing it in _Mathematica_ would defeat the whole point of it being "snappy", no? :P

Comment: @R.M. I just want to use Mathematica to make pretty pictures, so speed isn't an issue.  I'll probably end up just doing a library link thingummy anyway.  But native is nicer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Snappy has many library bindings that could be used to link it to Mathematica. A reimplementation in a slow language like Mathematica doesn't seem very helpful. I would first try simply calling the Java binding which could be packed into a Mathematica package and you're done.